# wrapr seems not to work with vectors

Tags: r, data.table

Following works with a `c()` but fails with `qc()`

This works:

```
library(wrapr)
library(data.table)


dtest <- data.table(x=1:10,y=letters[1:10])
for (i in 1:nrow(dtest)){
  print(paste(i,c(dtest[i,2])))
}
#> [1] "1 a"
#> [1] "2 b"
#> [1] "3 c"
#> [1] "4 d"
#> [1] "5 e"
#> [1] "6 f"
#> [1] "7 g"
#> [1] "8 h"
#> [1] "9 i"
#> [1] "10 j"
```

Now if you replace `c` by `qc`, this doesn't work.

```
library(wrapr)
library(data.table)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:wrapr':
#> 
#>     :=
dtest <- data.table(x=1:10,y=letters[1:10])
for (i in 1:nrow(dtest)){
  print(paste(i,qc(dtest[i,2])))
}
#> Error in eval(ei): object 'dtest' not found
```

Comment: its working for me.

Comment: What is the output you get? @PKumar

Comment: the same as the first function. try using: `wrapr::qc`

Comment: There’s a bug (name clash) detected inside wrapr function. Awaiting for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about that, it turned out to be a name collision in the wrapr code. I have documented and fixed it in the dev version of wrapr (available [here](https://github.com/WinVector/wrapr)).

Thanks for reporting that and sorry about the trouble.

Also the fixed version is just going to capture the source code and not evaluate the expression. I have added some documentation to emphasize that qc() is "quoiting c()", it has different (more aggressive) quoting behavior- doesn't just convert argument values to strings (instead captures names as strings).

```
library(wrapr)
library(data.table)
dtest <- data.table(x=1:10,y=letters[1:10])
for (i in 1:nrow(dtest)){
     print(paste(i,qc(dtest[i,2])))
   }
# [1] "1 dtest[i, 2]"
# [1] "2 dtest[i, 2]"
# [1] "3 dtest[i, 2]"
# [1] "4 dtest[i, 2]"
# [1] "5 dtest[i, 2]"
# [1] "6 dtest[i, 2]"
# [1] "7 dtest[i, 2]"
# [1] "8 dtest[i, 2]"
# [1] "9 dtest[i, 2]"
# [1] "10 dtest[i, 2]"
```